# How to group by in Pandas, and get the common elements in a list?

Tags: pandas

I have the below pandas df, and is the sample.

```
    cars            ID   scores
    Car1            2     1
    Car2            2     1
    Car1            2     2
    Car2            2     2
```

Below is the code for creating the data frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cars': ['Car1', 'Car2', 'Car1', 'Car2'],
    'ID': [2, 2, 2, 2],
    'scores': [1, 1, 2, 2]
})
```

I have been trying to create an output something like this, wherein I can pivot/groupby ID, and get the common cars in a list and scores in a list as well.

```
{ 'cars': ['Car1', 'Car2'], 'ID': 2, 'scores': [1, 2]}
```

I have tried the below code, and other groupby functions, but nothing seems to work. Can you please suggest how do I go about it?

```
output = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='cars', values='points').reset_index()

# convert the output to a dictionary
result = output.to_dict(orient='list')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html), then convert [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
out = (df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)
         .agg(lambda x: list(x.unique()))
         .to_dict('records')
       )
```

You will get a list of dictionaries, one per ID.

Output:

```
[{'ID': 2, 'cars': ['Car1', 'Car2'], 'scores': [1, 2]}]
```